# keystone.Storage adaptor for google cloud storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-storage, keystonejs

Is there a google cloud storage adaptor for keystone.Storage library?

I want to host everything that I can with one service provider. I am going to use google cloud platform to host my Keystone.js app and MongoDB database.

The library has a adaptor for local files, S3 and Azure, but I don't know how to use it with google cloud storage.

See https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/lib/storage

I would be great if it can be used like the keystone-storage-adapter-s3:

Configure:

```js
var storage = new keystone.Storage({
  adapter: require('keystone-storage-adapter-gcloud'),
  s3: {
    key: 'gcloud-key',
    secret: 'secret',
    bucket: 'mybucket',
    path: '/profilepics',
    headers: {},
  },
  schema: {
    bucket: true,
    etag: true,
    path: true,
    url: true,
  },
});
```

Then use it as the storage provider for a File field:

```js
File.add({
  name: { type: String },
  file: { type: Types.File, storage: storage },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [GCP Adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystone-storage-adapter-cloud-storage?activeTab=readme) for Keystone. It's not officially part of Keystone but the format in which it is used is close to how you described yours.

I know it has been quite some time since this question was asked so I am assuming you managed to solve this problem. I'm leaving this for the sake of those who come after this answer. Hope it helped!